# Got permission denied in ssh in aws instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I have install `git` in my EC2 instance.

```
git version 2.14.5
```

I have create a new IAM user and give codeCommit permission.

In next, I have follow all the steps one by one from this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-ssh-unixes.html?icmpid=docs_acc_console_connect_np). which works fine.

At the 8th step I have add this code in my `config` file.

```
Host git-codecommit.*.amazonaws.com
User {{SSH KEY ID}}
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Then I have assign `600` to config.

And then I have fire this command to test my SSH.

```
ssh git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
```

**Error**

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Can any one help me to fixed this issue ?

Comment: Are you trying to ssh into CodeCommit? Is this to retrieve a repo? If you are wanting to retrieve a repo, this is normally done with `git clone ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/repo-name`

Answer (score 1):

Can you retry the process with 400 permission on the ssh key

```
chmod 400 <key>.pem
```

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to access a repository from CodeCommit, you can do it with:

```
git clone ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/repo-name
```

If you try to ssh directly to CodeCommit, the connection will be denied with the message:

> You have successfully authenticated over SSH. You can use Git to interact with AWS CodeCommit. Interactive shells are not supported.

Comment: Yes, I got this message too. So how could I fixed this ?

Comment: You do not fix it. You should use the above command to clone a repo. You should _not_ be using `ssh` to login — it is merely a communications protocol that the `git clone` command will use.